# Understanding Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I have heard of functions being Lipschitz Continuous several times in my classes yet I have never really seemed to understand exactly what this concept really is.

Here is the definition.

$\left | f(x_{1})-f(x_{2}) \right |\leq K\left | x_{1}-x_{2} \right |$

Here is the function I'm using. It is known that this is Lipschitz Continuous.

$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+5}$

If you pick some points. Here I picked (1, 0.408) and (2, 0.66).

The result is:

$\left | 0.252 \right |\leq K\left | 1 \right |$

So as long as K is 0.252 or bigger then this function is Lipschitz Continuous?

What if I pick K to be 0.0001 is the function no longer Lipschitz Continuous?

To me this is hard to understand, why not always pick K to be very large such that the function is always Lipschitz Continuous?

Unless the left hand side of the inequality is infinity, can't you always find a K big enough to satisfy this inequality?

Comment: The intuitive idea is that the derivative is bounded by a constant (for differentiable functions).

Comment: The answer to your last question is no!, see my answer please.

Comment: Here's some geometric intuition, for all that it's worth. Suppose $|f(x) - f(y)| \le M|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in[a,b]$. Then the graph of $f$ lies wedged in between the line of slope $M$ going through $f(a)$ at $a$, and the line of slope $-M$ going through $f(a)$ at $a$.

Comment: The same $K$ is supposed to apply for **all** pairs $x_1,x_2$, not just one pair.

Answer (score 23):

Lipschitz continuity doesn't say that if you take any old $x,y$ and plot $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$. It says that $M$ is *fixed* and the inequality holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ . This is much stronger of a condition. If all you needed to do was pick some $M$ for every choice of $x,y$, the condition would mean nothing.

If your function is differentiable, Lipschitz continuity just says that the function has bounded derivative. I think of this as a "wiggling" and "stretching" bound.

For the stretching, it says that a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ can't grow too fast. For example, if the Lipschitz constant were $1$ and $f(0)=0$, then it is trapped between the two lines $y=x-1,x+1$. This essentially means that it can't grow too quickly, or wiggle too much.

If the constant $M <1$, a function is said to be a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) which has many nice properties as well.

--

Comment: You wrote, "If the Lipschitz constant were $1$ and $f(0)=0$, then it is trapped between the two lines $y=x-1, x+1$". Are you sure this is correct? For example, $f(x)=-x$ satisfies the Lipscihtz continuity for $K=1$, but $f(x)=-x$ is not trapped by the two lines $y=x-1, x+1$. (I think it is trapped between the two lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$.)

Answer (score 11):

You can not pick K sufficiently enough for a function to be Lipschitz continuous if they are not. That's the main point of that kind of continuity. If $f$ is not lipschitz continuous, and you say that $K = 10^6$, I can find an pair of points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \geq 10^6|x_1 - x_2|$.

Think about the mean value theorem and Lipschitz continuity.

Mean value theorem says if $f$ is continuous at [a,b] and differentiable at (a,b), then

$\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $\displaystyle\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$.

Lipschitz says that

$\exists K > 0, \forall a,b \in D_f,\mbox{ such that } \displaystyle\frac{|f(b) - f(a)|}{|b - a|} \leq K$.

Then if the derivative of $f$ as a function is bounded, then $f$ will be Lipschitz.

Consider the case

$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ for $x \in [0,1]$, then $f$ is not Lipschitz, since $\displaystyle\sup_{x \in [0,1]}f'(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = +\infty$.

Also, as an additional note if a function $f$ defined on $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz continuous then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$.

Comment: how is sup f'(x) related to that limit when x->0, why not the limit when x->1?

Comment: Because the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ in which the sup of the derivative is at the point where it goes to infinity. The limit as $x \to 1$ of $f'(x)$ is just 1, while the $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x) = \infty$ which is the supremum.

Answer (score 1):

Definition: f is Lipschitz iff there exists $K>0$ such that for all $x,y\in dom(f)$ we have $$(1)\quad |f(x)-f(y)|<K |x-y|.$$ For $S\subset dom(f)$ we say $f$ is Lipschitz on $S$ to mean that $f$ restricted to the domain $S$ is a Lipschitz function. This is most commonly done when $S$ is an interval or a half-line.

The value of $K$ is not unique, for if (1) holds for all $x,y\in  dom (f)$ then it will hold with $K$ replaced by $42K.$ What matters is whether $at$ $least$ $one$ $K>0$ exists such that (1)  holds for all $x,y \in dom(f).$

Answer (score 0):

Lipschitz continuity gives you a bound on how fast things can be pulled appart in the image.

**Setup**

- Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map between metric spaces.
- Suppose that $\omega:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is continuous and fixes 0. We think of this map as "quantifying the maximum rate at which nearby points can get pulled appart by our map".  We call this $\omega$ the *modulus of continuity of f*.
- Let x and z be points in $X$.

**Explanation**
If x and z are close, say their distance $d(x,z)$ is $1/10^{1000}$ then their images in $Y$ under f, say, $f(x)$ and $f(z)$ are also close.  Moreover, we can say how close they must at-least be; precisely, they are no more than $\omega(1/10^{1000})$ appart.

Likewise, if both points are far, say their distance $d(x,z)$ is $1000000$ then their images in $Y$ under f, say, $f(x)$ and $f(z)$ are no more than $\omega(1000000)$ appart.  So these two points can be far appart but no further than $\omega(1000000)$.

If $X$ is compact, eg $[0,1]$ with Euclidean distance, then such an $\omega$ must exist.  However, there's generally no guarantee that it's easy to work with.  This is where the *Lipschitz* condition comes in.  It postulates that the thing quantifying the worst case stretching, namely $\omega$, is a *linear map* ($\omega(t)=Kt$ as opposed to something say wierd like $\omega(t)=\max\{t,\sqrt{t}\}$).

---

**Background**
The Lipschitz condition becomes reasonable, due the the Rademacher-Stephanov Theorem.
In the case where X and Y are Euclidean, which states that a function in a compact X is Lipschitz iff it is almost everywhere differentiable with uniformly bounded gradient.