# Compare Lipschitz constants for Two different Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning, lipschitz-functions, neural-networks

This is about Lipschitz constant and a function $f$ is defined and continuous on an interval $[a,b]$, and is differentiable on the interior $(a,b)$ and $x,y \in [a, b]$. I understand you can write:

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M |x - y|$$

where $M$ is the smallest value for which the previous inequality is true, called the Lipschitz constant. Building on this, assume we have two different functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ then 
$$|f_1(x) - f_1(y)| \le M_1 |x - y|$$ 
and 
$$|f_2(x) - f_2(y)| \le M_2 |x - y|$$

My questions:

1. If $M_1 > M_2$, can we compare the 2 Lipschitz constants ($M_1$ and $M_2$) for two different functions? Is it even correct to compare them?
2. What kind of inferences can we make if $M_1 > M_2$?
3. Assume $f_1$ and $f_2$ are non-convex functions (machine learnt models), since $M_1 > M_2$, can we say that $f_1$ has converged to a better minima than $f_2$?

Comment: [This movie-graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#/media/File:Lipschitz_Visualisierung.gif) may help. Larger Lipschitz constants correspond to the requirement of having to use cones with larger aperture angles.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, i see. is that all we can say? Can we infer anything more about 1  and 2 if 1 is greater than 2? I am asking this from a machine learning and function optimization perspective.

Comment: I don't know anything about machine learning (except maybe [this](https://www.google.com/search?q="My+CPU+is+a+neural+net+processor") from 1991), but you can think of the Lipschitz constant as a bound on how rapidly a function's value can change when you change its input values. Lipschitz continuous means that the function's values can't increase or decrease more than some constant times the change in its input values, and the larger the Lipschitz constant, the more the function's values are allowed to change (i.e. $M_1 > M_2$ means $f_1$ can increase/decrease more rapidly than $f_2).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro haha love the terminator reference :) Your explanation made sense to me. Pertaining to what you wrote, where can I find more theory on this? i.e. larger the Lipschitz constant, the more the function's values are allowed to change. I am assuming there are some proofs on this.

Comment: I googled [intuitive + "Lipschitz continuity"](https://www.google.com/search?q=intuitive+%22Lipschitz+continuity%22) and found these that I believe will be helpful: [Intuitive idea of the Lipschitz function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353276/13130) *AND* [Understanding Lipschitz Continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374289/13130) *AND* [What is the intuition behind uniform continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3241309/13130).  **Note:** Uniform continuity on a set is when, given an "epsilon", we can find a single "delta" that works for that "epsilon" **(continued)**

Comment: for every point in the set. Every uniformly continuous function has a [modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) associated with it, and Lipschitz continuity is when the modulus of continuity can be chosen to be a linear function. I say "can be chosen", rather than "is", because of how "modulus of continuity" is defined. If $\omega(t)$ is a modulus of continuity for some function and specified domain set, then any function that approaches zero slower than $\omega(t)$ does will also be a modulus of continuity for that function.

Comment: Incidentally, if no one else gives an answer to this question, I'll try to assemble the information into an answer at some point, when I have time (and remember to do so).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro If you can assemble this as a coherent answer, you will get my upvote and "answer" accept.