# Why is f continuous when $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid \leq \mid x-y \mid$?

Tags: functions, continuity

In a proof it was said that for a real value function $f$ that from $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid \leq \mid x-y \mid$ it follows that f is continuous. Why is that?

Well in the problem the domain of the function was $[0,1]$ but it suppose it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you know the definition of continuity?

Comment: Yes. Maybe is obvious but I don't see it :)

Comment: Please see this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374289/understanding-lipschitz-continuity

Comment: $\delta =\epsilon$?

Comment: Choose $\delta=\epsilon$ and the condition for continuity is met immediately.

Comment: oh... that was easy... thanks

Comment: @LazarIonutRadu Great. I don't want to use the word "obvious". So  in simple terms, the definition says that "if $|x-y|$ is small, then we should be able to make $|f(x)-f(y)|$ small as well". Can you see how the condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$ guarantees that?